# How can I set my default question/answer sort on my user page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, preferences

I like to look at my recent activity a lot and when i go to my user page to look at questions and answers, they're always sorted by votes first, when what I'd like is ordering by date by default.  Is there a way to enforce a default ordering or remember my last preferred ordering?  A client side cookie would seem sufficient.

Comment: That'd be nice. I usually do click "newest" as I want to see how my recent answers are doing.

Comment: can someone edit this tag to feature-request

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a script (greasemonkey) that will auto-sort questions by date for you: [How to make "recent" activity by default?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/how-to-make-recent-activity-by-default/3913#3913)