# How to make "recent" activity by default?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, sorting, preferences

I want whenever I'll open my profile my asked and answered questions should be sorted "Recent" by default, it is currently sorted on the basis of VOTES.

Is there anything I can do this, or this is a pending feature from SO :) If its pending then I request SO team to add this whenever possible :)

Comment: Seconded. And to get to 15 characters, seconded again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be nice if the system remembered my last selected sort.  It does this with answers in a question page.

Comment: I think this is an excellent suggestion.  If I go to my profile page I would like it to default to the last view I used(recent,newest,votes etc).  It should probably default to votes for other users, but it would save many clicks of the recent button.

Comment: It occurs to me also that some of the high load on SO is due to pages having to be reloaded for sort selection.

Answer (score 1):

#### Auto-sort Profile Questions by Date...

The following greasemonkey-script will auto-sort profile-questions by date (giving most recent first)

```
(function(){
  function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
      $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
    }
  }
  GM_wait();
  function letsJQuery() {
    if ($(".tabs-question-user a:eq(3)").html() == "recent") {
        $.post($(".tabs-question-user a:eq(3)").attr("href"), function(data){
            $("#questions-table").html(data);
        });
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: While that's cool, I don't think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: Oops. You're right, Kyle. The script has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see any problem with this as a request, I do not see any real pressing need why it should be ASAP. I don't think hitting the preferred sort style every time you view the page is too much of a difficulty right now that can't wait for a while.

Comment: Ya right ASAP is not required. Edited the post, I am just pointing the problem which I face. Recent activity is normally required, what's the use of displaying highest voted question first ? If I have recent activity then I can see that is there any new answer or comment on ma question.