# How do I get a link to my User Stats sorted by recent

Tags: support, users, profile-page

I find myself going to stackoverflow and wanting to see recent activity on my questions that I asked or things that I've answered, so the flow usually goes:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/
2. Click username [dougnukem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98050/dougnukem)
3. Click the "recent" sorting option
4. look at any recent changes

I'd like to create a bookmark that brings me to my user page and lets me view my recent activity and other people's activity on my questions/answers.

I tried going to the link that is associated with the sort button but it seems to be some weird non-styled result:

- Dougnukem activity link: https://stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=98050&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/how-to-make-recent-activity-by-default

Answer (score 1):

A *bit* late, and meanwhile clicking the envelope to get to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/ gives one better recent updates, but still: https://stackoverflow.com/users/98050/dougnukem?sort=recent

And [since June](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28584/back-arrow-to-recent-activity/55311#55311), the Back button generates links like `#qpage_1-apage_3-qsort_votes-asort_newest`. Such links can be used to scroll right to the answers and set sorting.