# Back arrow to recent activity

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity

I am reviewing my open questions (some are on page 4 or 5), so I click the page number "4" and get a list of questions.

I click on the question, I go read it, and then hit the back button to go back and see the next question, it takes me back to the first page of my questions, not to where I actually was.

Should I not be hitting the back button?

Comment: "So I click the page number "4" and then come back to "  Come back to what?  The future?  Canada?  Do, a deer, a female deer?  **INQUIRING MINDS NEED TO KNOW!**

Comment: Looks like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30342/browser-back-doesnt-work-properly-on-recently-asked-questions complains of the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one makes me feel pretty good:

The back button now works as expected in the user page:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/109035/raj-more#qpage_4-apage_3-qsort_votes-asort_votes

Also pages are linkable for an add bonus.

Comment: +10000000000000

Comment: Absolutely love this new feature. Even if tabbed browsing mitigates the problem, this implementation is a time saver when you accidentally miss your middle click on page 42/66.

Comment: Awesome, waffles!

Comment: Nice one. While you're at it, there's also [the ajax on the user/tag search pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/user-search-versus-the-back-button/49390#49390). :)

Answer (score 4):

No, do not hit the back button here. Open your questions in tabs!

Watch the address bar when you click page 4. It shows the same URL than page 1. Therefore the back button cannot distinguish these pages. Believe me, tabbed browsing is really great to solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah, the ajax pretty much renders the back button useless here.

Comment: AJAX FAIL! BOOOOO!

Comment: @Shog9, its fixed now :)

Comment: @waffles: excellent...

Answer (score 3):

There's nowhere to go "back" to here because you haven't left the page..