# Browser "Back" doesn't work properly on "Recently asked questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [back arrow to recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28584/back-arrow-to-recent-activity)

#### STR:

1. Click your username
2. On the "stats" tab, click on "recent"
3. Click any question
4. Press "Back" in browser.

#### Actual:

You're back to the list of questions sorted by "votes"

#### Expected:

You're back exactly where you were.

(It is also currently impossible to bookmark the "my questions by recency" page.)

Comment: what browser do you see this in?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28584/back-arrow-to-recent-activity

Answer (score 2):

First up, changing the sort order does not really count as navigation, and why should it? You are getting the exact same information, but just in a different order. The data being sorted with JS is the ideal solution.

To fix the broken navigation, I would suggest the use of `#anchors` to indicate the current sort method. `/users/131346/joshhunt` would give me my/the default sort method, but when you click on `votes`, the URL changes to `/users/131346/joshhunt#sort-by-votes` in order to make the back buttons work. The anchor name could be as verbose as needed because anchors are never sent to the server as a part of the URL.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the most common way to fix this. I take your point about how it's not exactly "navigation" when you change the sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Turning JS off leads me to this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?userid=135197&page=1&pagesize=30&sort=recent

Ain't pretty (and you'll need to put your own userID in), but it works. Ajax in general is much nicer than proper links for things like sorting - shouldn't have to reload everything to sort one item!

Comment: I got to that page too by copying link location and just going to it. It's not pretty indeed. Re "nicer" - that's subjective :) I think it's nicer when "back" and bookmarks work. AJAX doesn't _have_ to break them though.