# user search versus the back button

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-list

1. go to users page on stackoverflow.com
2. type in 'f*ck you' (using the obvious spelling)
3. observe two users
4. click on one
5. hit the back button

You don't go back to the list.

I see something that this may be a dup of, but it is all concerned with multi-pagination, not with returning the the search list. However, I may have misunderstood.

Comment: It's the same thing with Tag Search. I sense Jeff warming up the `[status-bydesign]` edit right now.

Comment: @Jeff, @Jon - shouldn't it at least be `[status-declined]`, surely it wasn't a deliberate "design" to work like that?

Comment: @Jeff it might be a design choice, but it's a lousy one. Usability fail all the way!

Answer (score 6):

**`[status-bydesign]`**?? Come on @Jeff, ajax is no reason to break the back button...

**Greasemonkey to the rescue**:

```
(function() {
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
        } else { 
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
        }
    }
    GM_wait();
    function letsJQuery() {
        $(function() {
            var textbox = $("#userfilter, #tagfilter");
            var oldHash = "";
            if (textbox.length > 0) {
                textbox.unbind("keydown").typeWatch({ highlight: true, wait: 500, captureLength: -1, callback: almostFinished }); 
                setInterval(function() {
                    var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
                    if (oldHash != hash) {
                        textbox.val(hash);
                        oldHash = hash;
                        unsafeWindow.finished(hash);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
            function almostFinished(txt) {
                location.hash = txt;
                oldHash = txt;
                unsafeWindow.finished(txt);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Apply to `http://*stackoverflow.com/users*` and `http://*stackoverflow.com/tags*` to get the back button working on tag/user searches (should also work on their SU/SF counter parts).

**`[status-completed]`** ;)

Comment: +1 I changed it a little so it also works as a chrome extension: http://pastebin.org/216251

Comment: Ill have a think about this, I'm not sure I want to be changing a windows location so frequently, perhaps I'll reset it when you navigate out.

Answer (score 1):

Search results are done through ajax and results are writing html table into the page from javascript, so if you use back button, default page 1 will display.