# Implement ajax back button support in the user page, paging

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, back-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [back arrow to recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28584/back-arrow-to-recent-activity)

I always find it kind of annoying that the back button "breaks" when I am browsing through my questions and answers in the user page.

For example, if I go to page 2 and then click back, it takes me to the page I was on before.

It would be nice if history was maintained using the gmail iframe hack http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html .

Comment: I [wrote a greasemonkey script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/user-search-versus-the-back-button/49390#49390) to fix a very similar issue in /tags & /users... If you're interested, I could probably adapt it for this if you can live with a greasemonkey fix instead of a "real" one.

Comment: @Alconja, I really would prefer if this was implemented in SO, for one my browser of choice is chrome and Im not sure if I can get greasemonkey going on it.