# Please don't prioritize answers in the new profile page query strings

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, navigation

I was testing out the new [back functionality on profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28584/back-arrow-to-recent-activity/55311#55311). It works great, except for one part. If I have ever changed the page on my answers, then when I navigate back to the page via the "Back" button, then my page will always focus itself on the answers. This overrides the fact that, for example, I last changed the page on my questions and I clicked a question specifically.

It's most likely derived from the fact that the querystring just considers `qpage` and `apage`, and with so little to work with I can understand that it's pretty difficult to define which one was actually the last hit while maintaining both page points. I think the maintenance of both page points is more important than correcting the auto-navigation, so I can be satisfied with declining this request if it's too much trouble. But it would be very convenient to actually be pointed at where I was last at, rather than always answers.

---

On a related but much smaller and curiosity-inspired note, is it only on my end with this office machine that there's a horrendous scroll effect that occurs for said auto-navigation? Does everyone else get a very nice "zip" that just puts them at the destination? Or is this slow and cumbersome scroll effect caused by the site itself? It doesn't need to be changed or anything (and this could be addressed simply in comments), but it wouldn't hurt to know if that was something on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, this should be cleaned up a bit. I'm thinking:

1. No scroll effect for back navigation
2. Store an anchor in the history, so it knows where to navigate to.

I will sort this out but it may take a bit. Ping me in 2-3 weeks if its not done.

Comment: Seems to be implemented now, at least the important one (point 2). Thank you much!