# Lock user stat page view to "newest"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, profile-page, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set my default question/answer sort on my user page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/how-can-i-set-my-default-question-answer-sort-on-my-user-page)

How do I lock my Stack Overflow / Meta user stat page view to "newest"?

On every refresh my page moves to "votes" mode

Comment: Ok - this has actually been asked already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/how-can-i-set-my-default-question-answer-sort-on-my-user-page
Short answer: it's not possible. Long answer: Greasemonkey. Huh... well, it looks longer when Jonathan writes it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a view should remain once you have picked it. That's how it has always worked for me on all of the SOFU sites.

**EDIT:** I'm referring to viewing questions above, not on the user page.